# Do auto-implemented properties really generate private fields on compile?

Tags: c#, .net

[image]

After compiling and running the program with:

```
class Person
{
    private string surname;

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname
    {
        get { return surname;}
        set
        {
            surname = value;
        }
    }
}
```

One can see, from the image linked, there is no "name" private field shown.
Is it just Visual Studio not recognizing it, or is there something else going on?

I have read numerous times things like "As for your two C# examples, one is simply syntactic sugar for the other." or "A backing field will be created when compiling.".

What's the catch?

Comment: Just think about it.  How could they not? Otherwise, where would the data be stored when the setter executed ? But you can look at the IL code and see it if you want. Use Reflector.  http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/

Comment: Also, the private field will not be called `name`. It will be given an "unpronouncable" name, one that's not a valid C# identifier. This ensures that it doesn't conflict with any code *you* may have written that uses the identifier `name` for another purpose.

Comment: I suggest https://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The backing field isn't shown to you by the debugger.  That doesn't mean it isn't there, it simply means that the designers of the debugger didn't feel it was important for people debugging code to be looking at private backing fields of auto properties, given that they can simply access the data through the property itself.

Answer (score 2):

With a help of *reflection* you can get a report what's actually going on:

```
  using System.Reflection;

  ...

  var fields = typeof(Person)
    .GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .Select(field => field.Name);

  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, fields));
```

And get

```
 surname
 <Name>k__BackingField
```

As you can see the compiler *has created* the backing field `<Name>k__BackingField` for the auto property

Answer (score 2):

I compiled a project with this silly class:

```
using System;

namespace ApagueMe
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public string Asdf { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then, i opened the generated DLL in .NET Refletor. Look at the result:

```
public class Class1
{
    // Fields
    [CompilerGenerated, DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private string <Asdf>k__BackingField;

    // Properties
    public string Asdf
    {
        [CompilerGenerated]
        get
        {
            return this.<Asdf>k__BackingField;
        }
        [CompilerGenerated]
        set
        {
            this.<Asdf>k__BackingField = value;
        }
    }
}
```